# Is reducedness an open condition?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes

If $X$ is a (general) scheme and $X$ is reduced at $p$, i.e. $\mathscr{O}_{X,p}$ is reduced, does there necessarily exist an open neighborhood of $p$ on which $X$ is reduced, i.e. $\mathscr{O}_X(U)$ is reduced?

This should be true at least when $X$ is Noetherian, since one can pick generators for the nilradical of any affine neighborhood $U$ and kill them off. How generally is it true?

Comment: This question might be of some interest and relevance: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111576/localization-at-a-prime-ideal-is-a-reduced-ring

Comment: So what comes out of the link above is that in general it is not true that if a scheme is reduced at a point, then there exists a neighborhood of that point on which it is reduced.

Comment: On a positive side note, note that $X$ is reduced if and only if $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ is reduced for all open subsets $U$ of $X$.

Comment: Just to put a bow on it after all these years, the linked duplicate shows that the answer is **yes** if $X$ is locally noetherian and **no** in general.